# How change an non-equivalency relation to equivalency relation?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, equivalence-relations

I am an engineer, so maybe this question is naive.

I study equivalence relations and equivalence classes. An equivalence relation is a binary relation that is reflexive, symmetric, and transitive.  Any number is equal to itself (reflexive). If a = b, then b = a (symmetric). If a = b, and b = c, then a=c (transitive). The relation that does not satisfy these conditions is not an equivalence relation.

For example, orthogonality is a non-equivalency relation on a set of lines in $\ R^2$. Because it is not reflexive and transitive.

I want to know: is there any maneuver or algorithm in math that changes a non-equivalency relation to an equivalency relation? For instance, by limitation in space set or adding some conditions.

Comment: Ethan's nice answer below is essentially "removing conditions" to get a relation which is an equiv rel, since you end up with more related things. This is also discussed [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/83899/). The process of "adding conditions" to get an equiv rel is discussed a bit [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4568344/473276). Both of these procedures can change the relation quite radically - there is generally no reason that you should end up with a "similar" relation. EG the transitive closure of the orthogonality relation on lines in $\Bbb R^3$ relates everything!

Comment: An easy way to get reflexivity,  is to modify your relation to be refinement of equality, for example < is not reflexive, but ≤ is. Now, in this case we already have reflexivity. You can force symmetry in a trivial way, lets say we have a relation xRy, we can consider the modified relation S where xSy iff xRy OR yRx. Then S is reflexive. For transitivity, the modifications are more complicated, the most natural being related to the transitive closure.

Comment: A simpler modification, is to notice that a nonempty subset of an equivalence relation is an equivalence relation. So take any equivalence relation R, which intersects your relation S, and consider S ∩ R as your equivalence relation

Answer (score 2):

You can always start with a relation and add to it all the pairs you need to make it an equivalence relation.

For reflexivity, add the pairs $(x,x)$ if they are not there.

For symmetry, add $(y,x)$ if it's not there and $(x,y)$ is.

For transitivity, form the [transitive closure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transitive_closure).

Whether these additions to the relation $R$ make any sense in the context that led to $R$ in the first place is application specific.
For example, if you apply this construction to the orthogonality relation for lines in the plane you end up with the relation that says two lines are equivalent just when they are orthogonal or parallel.

Comment: Ethan if I'm not mistaken, an orthogonality relationship already does the same thing, so I didn't get the point of your procedure.

Comment: You note correctly that the orthogonality relation is neither transitive nor reflexive. You ask how to  "change it" to an equivalence relation. You can do that by adding pairs of lines you deem "equivalent". The minimal way to do that is to add all pairs of parallel lines (allowing lines to be parallel to themselves). So now lines are equivalent if they are parallel or perpendicular.

Comment: So, the nature of the equivalency classes also changes by adding non-existent conditions, in the procedure of changing a non-equivalence relation into an equivalence relation.

Comment: Yes, The set of equivalence classes determines the relation and vice versa, so when one changes the other must.

Comment: Hi Ethan. By "you might have to do the last two steps recursively", do you mean you have to apply the steps repeatedly? I think there is never a need to do any of these steps more than once, because the transitive closure of a symmetric relation is symmetric. (in a sense, step $3$ "computes the components" of an undirected graph, and it's clear that should give a partition)

Comment: @IzaakvanDongen Right. Will edit.

Comment: Regarding your comment "So, the nature of...", keep in mind that orthogonality is *not* an equivalence relation, one does not define equivalence classes unless a relation is an equivalence relation, and hence equivalence classes of the orthogonality relation are *undefined*.

Comment: Nonetheless what one could say, on top of this answer, is this: For any binary relation $R$ on a set $X$, the procedure described in this answer defines an equivalence relation $\sim$, and the partition of $X$ into equivalence classes for $\sim$ is the *smallest* partition having the property that if $x R y$ then $x \sim y$.